# Synchronous stream of responses from a stream of requests with RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm new to RxJS and was wondering if anyone could help me.

I want to create a synchronous stream of responses (preferably with the corresponding requests) from a stream of requests(payload data).

I basically want the requests to be sent one by one, each waiting for the response from the last one.

I tried this, but it sends everything at once ( [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tivehinere/edit?js,console) ):

```js
var requestStream, responseStream;
requestStream = Rx.Observable.from(['a','b','c','d','e']);

responseStream = requestStream.flatMap(
  sendRequest,
  (val, response)=>{ return {val, response}; }
);

responseStream.subscribe(
  item=>{
    console.log(item);
  },
  err => {
    console.err(err);
  },
  ()=>{
    console.log('Done');
  }
);

function sendRequest(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve('result for '+val);},1000);
  });
};
```

The following works, to an extent, but does not use stream for the request data ( [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/poyabutudi/edit?js,console) ).

```js
var data, responseStream;
data = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
responseStream = Rx.Observable.create(observer=>{
  var sendNext = function(){
    var val = data.shift();
    if (!val) {
      observer.onCompleted();
      return;
    }
    sendRequest(val).then(response=>{
      observer.onNext({val, response});
      sendNext();
    });
  };
  sendNext();
});

responseStream.subscribe(
  item=>{
    console.log(item);
  },
  err => {
    console.err(err);
  },
  ()=>{
    console.log('Done');
  }
);

function sendRequest(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve('response for '+val);},Math.random() * 2500 + 500);
  });
};
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, this is what I wanted to achieve:

"Send A, when you receive response for A, send B, when you receive response for B, send C, etc..."

Using concatMap and defer, as suggested by user3743222, seems to do it ( [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ciregezoru/edit?js,console) ):

```js
responseStream = requestStream.concatMap(
  (val)=>{
    return Rx.Observable.defer(()=>{
      return sendRequest(val);
    });
  },
  (val, response)=>{ return {val, response}; }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `flatMap` with `concatMap` in your first code sample and let me know if the resulting behaviour corresponds to what you are looking for.

```
responseStream = requestStream.concatMap(//I replaced `flatMap`
  sendRequest,
  (val, response)=>{ return {val, response}; }
);
```

Basically `concatMap` has a similar signature than `flatMap`, the difference in behaviour being that it will wait for the current observable being flattened to complete before proceeding with the next one. So here:

- a `requestStream` value will be pushed to the `concatMap` operator.
- the `concatMap` operator will generate a `sendRequest` observable, and whatever values out of that observable (seems to be a tuple `(val, response)`) will be passed through the selector function and the object result of that will be passed downstream
- when that `sendRequest` completes, another `requestStream` value is processed.
- In short, your requests will be processed one by one

Alternatively, maybe you want to use `defer` to defer the execution of the `sendRequest`.

```
responseStream = requestStream.concatMap(//I replaced `flatMap`
  function(x){return Rx.Observable.defer(function(){return sendRequest(x);})},
  (val, response)=>{ return {val, response}; }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your solution, but the requests are still all sent immediately. The documentation suggests that flatMap may cause interleaving whereas concatMap does not. It seems that the difference is in ordering. It makes sense to use concatMap but it still does not produce the desired behavior: Send A, when you receive response for A, send B, when you receive response for B, send C, etc..

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you wanted. Can you try in that case `defer`?   I will update the code

Comment: @user3743222 how can we emit an a string like 'loading url..' just before making the web request?